# How can i compare generic types in java?

Tags: java, interface, compareto

Hello everyone i'm stuck on comparing generic types in java.

```
public class Odev1LinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> extends AbstractLinkedList<T>{
    /**
     * Bir listede elemanları uygun konuma ekler. Boş bir listeye elemanlar eklendikten
     * sonra küçükten büyüğe sıralı olur
     * @param value eklenecek değer
     */
    @Override
    public void insertInOrder(T value) {
        Node current = this.getHead();
        Node previous = new Node<>(null,null);
        if(current == null){
            addFirst(value);
            return;
        }
        while(current != null){
            if(current.value >= value){
                if(current == this.getHead()){
                    addFirst(value);
                    return;
                }
                Node newNode = new Node<>(value,current);
                previous.next = newNode;
                return;
            }else if(current.next == null){
                addLast(value);
                return;
            }
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
```

I'm stuck at this line **if(current.value >= value)** ... Because sometimes my value comes String sometimes comes Integer this block is enough to compare integer but not good for String , how can i solve this problem.

My methods works like adding node in order -> If you have linked list like that {1,2,4} and when you use this method for adding new node which value is 3 . Your latest linked list must be like this {1,2,3,4}

```
{1,2,3,4} -> inserInOrder(5) -> {1,2,3,4,5}
{1,2,3,4} -> inserInOrder(0) -> {0,1,2,3,4}
{1,2,3,4} -> inserInOrder(2) -> {1,2,2,3,4}
```

And i need to make same think for String linked list. -> {"A","B","D"} ; inserInOrder("C") -> {"A","B","C","D"}

Comment: Have you looked at the `Comparable` documentation?

Comment: `if(current.value.compareTo(value) >= 0){`

Comment: i can't reach compareTo method

Comment: Please provide the class definition of `Node`.

Comment: i don't change the definition of node, it stored at my teacher's server

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use the "try-catch" block. Firstly, in the "try" block, you try to assign your value to a variable type of String. If it's ok, then your code executes further where you write comparing matching the String logic. But if it's not, then the ClassCastException is thrown which is caught by the "catch" block in which, in turn, you try to assign to value to a variable type if Integer and then perform the required logic.
Something like that:

```
try {
String variable = value
//String logic
} catch (Exception ClassCastException) {
int variable = value
//Integer logic
}
```